# Can a function parameter be used as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

In the following program, function `foo` receives parameter `v` of type `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`, which is used for passing in template argument `A<b>`:

```
template <bool>
struct A{};

constexpr bool foo(auto b) {
    return requires { typename A<b>; };
}

static_assert( foo( std::true_type{} ) );
```

Both GCC and MSVC find it valid (`foo` returns `true`), but in Clang `foo` returns `false`. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j6Mnqjvbz

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: Looks like a Clang bug since we can `use T = A<b>;` in the function body. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MdKo5qT8h

Comment: @康桓瑋 it's not really clear why it's clang bug, c++ doesn't have constexpr function arguments, and template parameters all must be constexpr

Comment: @Dmitry `bool_constant` has an implicit `bool` conversion function, `operator bool()`. Note that `A` accepts `bool` values, not `bool_constant` objects.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yeah, I see, since `operator bool()` marked as `constexpr` it is clearly clang bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have provided is correct. It fails because of a known [LLVM bug 42406 / issue 41751](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41751).

You can call member functions on objects that don't exist in constant expressions, as long as the member functions don't access the object. Two classic examples:

```cpp
std::array<int, 10> arr; // arr is not usable in a constant expression,
                         // but we can obtain its size()
static_assert(arr.size() == 10);

std::true_type t;
static_assert(t); // does not access t, but calls its operator bool()
```

Clang compiles both of the above.
The same logic extends to function parameters, which are never usable in a constant expression:

```cpp
// your code, except using std::true_type instead of auto
constexpr bool foo(std::true_type b) {
    return requires { typename A<b>; };
}
```

The code above should work, but results in a compiler error for clang:

> ```
> error: reference to local variable 'b' declared in enclosing function > 'foo'
>     7 |     return requires { typename A<b>; };
>       |                                  ^
> note: 'b' declared here
>     6 | constexpr bool foo(std::true_type b) {
>       |
> ```

Your static assertion fails for the same reason, though you can understand the issue better when avoiding templates. This error message is obviously nonsensical and a compiler bug because no reference is being declared.

Comment: It gets even weirder.  This is accepted (keeping all code in question and replacing only `foo`): `constexpr bool foo(auto b) {
 std::true_type x{};
 return requires { typename A<x>; };
}` but `constexpr bool foo() {
 std::true_type x{};
 return requires { typename A<x>; };
}` fails